# How do I export images for each device in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I'm struggling to export a header image for multiple devices in Sketch.

I design mobile first and I will take a large image and scale it down for the mobile header. I do the same for tablet, and website. Each device type will get its own header image based on the device.

But, how do I export this image and ensure that it's suitable for retina displays? If I export the following header image it ends up losing its "sharpness" for any device in-between mobile and tablet. Also exporting all 3 manually seems like a pain is there a plugin or a way to do this in Sketch?

[image]

I'm still learning Sketch and I had a hard time Googling this so asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Multiple export sizes for an artboard in Sketch]

I think I know what you're trying to do. The closest thing that you could get would be to create multiple `Export` sizes — and even save them as a `Slice Preset`.

With the style you have with the angled accent, it would probably be easier on the development side to have the source image, and apply a mask or overlaying image to get the effect you'd like.

[image: Sketch Layer Preferences - Flatten bitmap to @2x option selected]

Along this same thread, having `Flatten Bitmaps` set `to @2x` will make any image you import at ½ the size, so if you export it at 2x, you won't have any quality loss.

For example, if you imported a `1000x600` image, its layer dimensions would be resized to `500x300` within Sketch.

I hope this answered your question (even though it might not be the answer you wanted to hear).

Comment: Actually this answer hits the nail on the head!